# Como ler parâmetros QueryString em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, querystring

Como eu faço para recolher argumentos de uma página HTML?

Tipo eu tentei usar que nem o C# / ASP.NET:

```
var conteudo = Response.QueryString["usuario"];
```

Considerando uma query string como:

```
/default.html?usuario=pt
```

Ai ele me delvolveria o que estava depois do "=".

**Como obter o valor com JavaScript?**

Comment: no caso o que ele iria devolver seria o valor pt

Comment: recomendo a você a leitura do [ask]. O título de sua pergunta está apelativo e não descreve o seu problema

Comment: foi mal mas você sabe como utilizo o queryString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){
   /*
    Function: getUrlParameters
    Descrição: Obtem o valor dos parâmetros da URL atual ou URL estática
    Author: Tirumal
    URL: www.code-tricks.com
   */
   var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
       parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
       returnBool = true;

   for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
        parr = parArr[i].split("=");
        if(parr[0] == parameter){
            return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
            returnBool = true;
        }else{
            returnBool = false;            
        }
   }

   if(!returnBool) return false;  
}
```

Esse código foi retirado do site [Code-tricks](http://code-tricks.com/get-url-parameters-using-javascript/), você pode utilizá-la da seguinte forma:

A partir da localização atual da janela:

```
var parametro1 = getUrlParameters("nomeDoParametro", "", true);
```

De uma url estática:

```
var parametro1 = getUrlParameters("usuario", "http://www.exemplo.com/default.html?usuario=pt", true);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7wRw/)